# Read scanner input java

Tags: java

Having problem to read input with the scanner function. As of now my code look like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int total_weight = 0;
    
        do{
            int n_elements = sc.nextInt();
            if (n_elements == 0) {
                break;
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++) {
                int [] item_weights = new int[n_elements];
                item_weights[i] = sc.nextInt();
                total_weight += item_weights[i];
                System.out.println(item_weights[i]);
            }
            System.out.println(total_weight);
            System.out.println(n_elements);
            sc.nextLine();
            
        }while(sc.nextInt() != 0);
```

Input format is like this, read each line by line. (0 indicates end of data)

```
8 529 382 130 462 223 167 235 529
12 528 129 376 504 543 363 213 138 206 440 504 418
0
```

My code reads it like this,

```
529
382
130
462
223
167
235
529
2657
8
129
376
504
543
363
213
138
206
440
504
418
0
```

Missing some numbers when changing line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only reading `int` values. Remove `sc.nextLine();` and

```
while(sc.nextInt() != 0);
```

is consuming values as well. You are checking that the value entered was `0` and `break`ing earlier. So something like

```
do {
    int n_elements = sc.nextInt();
    if (n_elements == 0) {
        break;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++) {
        int[] item_weights = new int[n_elements];
        item_weights[i] = sc.nextInt();
        total_weight += item_weights[i];
        System.out.println(item_weights[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(total_weight);
    System.out.println(n_elements);
} while (sc.hasNextInt());
```

should fix the issue.